# How to use the saved neural network.ser in Android studio

Tags: java, android, netbeans, neural-network

I've trained a neural network in NetBeans and saved it as neural_network.ser by using Serializable ,"all classes implement Serializable" , Now I want to use it in my android application but when loading the network ,ClassNotFoundException raised .

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: neural_network.BackPropagation

Here is the Classes:

BackPropagation class:

```
public class BackPropagation extends  Thread  implements  Serializable
 {
   private static final String TAG = "NetworkMessage";
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -8862858027413741101L;
   private double   OverallError;
   // The minimum Error Function defined by the user
   private double   MinimumError;
   // The user-defined expected output pattern for a set of samples
   private double   ExpectedOutput[][];
   // The user-defined input pattern for a set of samples
   private double   Input[][];
   // User defined learning rate - used for updating the network weights
   private double   LearningRate;
   // Users defined momentum - used for updating the network weights
   private double   Momentum;
   // Number of layers in the network 
   private  int NumberOfLayers;
   // Number of training sets
   private  int NumberOfSamples;
   // Current training set/sample that is used to train network
   private  int SampleNumber;
   // Maximum number of Epochs before the traing stops training 
   private long MaximumNumberOfIterations;
   // Public Variables
   public LAYER Layer[];
   public  double   ActualOutput[][];
   long delay = 0;
   boolean die = false;
   // Calculate the node activations
   public void FeedForward()
    {
      int i,j;
      // Since no weights contribute to the output
      // vector from the input layer,
      // assign the input vector from the input layer
      // to all the node in the first hidden layer
      for (i = 0; i < Layer[0].Node.length; i++)
         Layer[0].Node[i].Output = Layer[0].Input[i];
      Layer[1].Input = Layer[0].Input;
      for (i = 1; i < NumberOfLayers; i++)
       {
         Layer[i].FeedForward();
         // Unless we have reached the last layer, assign the layer i's    //output vector
        // to the (i+1) layer's input vector
        if (i != NumberOfLayers-1)
            Layer[i+1].Input = Layer[i].OutputVector();
       }
  }
  // FeedForward()
  // Back propagated the network outputy error through
  // the network to update the weight values
public void UpdateWeights()
{
    CalculateSignalErrors();
    BackPropagateError();
}
 private void CalculateSignalErrors()
  {
    int i,j,k,OutputLayer;
    double Sum;
    OutputLayer = NumberOfLayers-1;
    // Calculate all output signal error
   for (i = 0; i < Layer[OutputLayer].Node.length; i++)
    { 
      Layer[OutputLayer].Node[i].SignalError =   
      (ExpectedOutput[SampleNumber][i] -Layer[OutputLayer].Node[i].Output) * 
      Layer[OutputLayer].Node[i].Output *  
      (1-Layer[OutputLayer].Node[i].Output);
    }
  // Calculate signal error for all nodes in the hidden layer
  // (back propagate the errors
 for (i = NumberOfLayers-2; i > 0; i--)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < Layer[i].Node.length; j++) 
     {
       Sum = 0;
       for (k = 0; k < Layer[i+1].Node.length; k++)
          Sum = Sum + Layer[i+1].Node[k].Weight[j] * 
          Layer[i+1].Node[k].SignalError;
       Layer[i].Node[j].SignalError = Layer[i].Node[j].Output*(1 -  
       Layer[i].Node[j].Output)*Sum;
     }
  }
}

private void BackPropagateError() 
 {
    int i,j,k;
    // Update Weights
    for (i = NumberOfLayers-1; i > 0; i--) 
      {
        for (j = 0; j < Layer[i].Node.length; j++) 
          {
            // Calculate Bias weight difference to node j
            Layer[i].Node[j].ThresholdDiff = LearningRate *
                    Layer[i].Node[j].SignalError +
                    Momentum*Layer[i].Node[j].ThresholdDiff;
            // Update Bias weight to node j
            Layer[i].Node[j].Threshold =
                    Layer[i].Node[j].Threshold +
                            Layer[i].Node[j].ThresholdDiff;
             // Update Weights
            for (k = 0; k < Layer[i].Input.length; k++) 
               {
                 // Calculate weight difference between node j and k
                 Layer[i].Node[j].WeightDiff[k] =
                         LearningRate *
                         Layer[i].Node[j].SignalError*Layer[i-
                         1].Node[k].Output +
                         Momentum*Layer[i].Node[j].WeightDiff[k];
                 // Update weight between node j and k
                 Layer[i].Node[j].Weight[k] =
                        Layer[i].Node[j].Weight[k] + 
                        Layer[i].Node[j].WeightDiff[k];
               }
          }
       }
  }
private void CalculateOverallError()
 {
    int i,j;
    OverallError = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < NumberOfSamples; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < Layer[NumberOfLayers-1].Node.length; j++)
         {
            OverallError = OverallError +
                    0.5*( Math.pow(ExpectedOutput[i][j] - ActualOutput[i] 
                                                                   [j],2) );
        }
}
 public  BackPropagation(int NumberOfNodes[],
                        double InputSamples[][],
                        double OutputSamples[][],
                        double LearnRate,
                        double Moment,
                        double MinError,
                        long MaxIter
                        )
  {
    int i,j;
 // Initiate variables
    NumberOfSamples = InputSamples.length;
    MinimumError = MinError;
    LearningRate = LearnRate;
    Momentum = Moment;
    NumberOfLayers = NumberOfNodes.length;
    MaximumNumberOfIterations = MaxIter;
 // Create network layers
    Layer = new LAYER[NumberOfLayers];
 // Assign the number of node to the input layer
    Layer[0] = new LAYER(NumberOfNodes[0],NumberOfNodes[0]);
 // Assign number of nodes to each layer
    for (i = 1; i < NumberOfLayers; i++)
        Layer[i] = new LAYER(NumberOfNodes[i],NumberOfNodes[i-1]);
    Input = new double[NumberOfSamples][Layer[0].Node.length];
    ExpectedOutput = new double[NumberOfSamples][Layer[NumberOfLayers-
    1].Node.length];
    ActualOutput = new double[NumberOfSamples][Layer[NumberOfLayers-
   1].Node.length];
    // Assign input set
    for (i = 0; i < NumberOfSamples; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < Layer[0].Node.length; j++)
            Input[i][j] = InputSamples[i][j];
    // Assign output set
    for (i = 0; i < NumberOfSamples; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < Layer[NumberOfLayers-1].Node.length; j++)
            ExpectedOutput[i][j] = OutputSamples[i][j];
} 
 public void TrainNetwork() 
  {
   int i,j;
   long k=0;
   do
    {
      // For each pattern
      for (SampleNumber = 0; SampleNumber < NumberOfSamples; SampleNumber++) 
      {
          for (i = 0; i < Layer[0].Node.length; i++)
              Layer[0].Input[i] = Input[SampleNumber][i];
          FeedForward();
        // Assign calculated output vector from network to ActualOutput
          for (i = 0; i < Layer[NumberOfLayers-1].Node.length; i++)
              ActualOutput[SampleNumber][i] = Layer[NumberOfLayers-
             1].Node[i].Output;
          UpdateWeights();
          // if we've been told to stop training, then
          // stop thread execution
          if (die){
              return;
          }
          // if
      }
      k++;
     // Calculate Error Function
      CalculateOverallError();
      System.out.println("OverallError = 
      "+Double.toString(OverallError)+"\n");
      System.out.print("Epoch = "+Long.toString(k)+"\n");
  } while ((OverallError > MinimumError) &&(k < MaximumNumberOfIterations));
}
  public LAYER[] get_layers() { return Layer; }
  // called when testing the network.
  public double[] test(double[] input) 
   {
     int winner = 0;
     NODE[] output_nodes;
     for (int j = 0; j < Layer[0].Node.length; j++)
     { Layer[0].Input[j] = input[j];}
     FeedForward();
     // get the last layer of nodes (the outputs)
     output_nodes = (Layer[Layer.length - 1]).get_nodes();
     double[] actual_output  = new double[output_nodes.length];
     for (int k=0; k < output_nodes.length; k++)
      {
        actual_output[k]=output_nodes[k].Output;
      } // for
    return actual_output;
 }//test()
  public double get_error() 
  {
     CalculateOverallError(); 
     return OverallError;
  } // get_error()
// to change the delay in the network
 public void set_delay(long time) 
  {
    if (time >= 0) {
        delay = time;
    } // if
}
//save the trained network
public void save(String FileName)
{
    try{


       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream (new File(FileName), true);
       // Serialize data object to a file
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        os.writeObject(this);
        os.close();
        fos.close();
        System.out.println("Network Saved!!!!");
    }
    catch (IOException E){System.out.println(E.toString());}
    catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e.toString());}
}


public  BackPropagation load(String FileName)
{

    BackPropagation myclass= null;
    try
    {

        //File patternDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()+"INDIAN_NUMBER_RECOGNITION.data");
        //patternDirectory.mkdirs();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(FileName));
        //FileInputStream fis =context.openFileInput(FileName);
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        myclass = (BackPropagation) is.readObject();
        System.out.println("Error After Reading = "+Double.toString(myclass.get_error())+"\n");
        is.close();
        fis.close();
        return myclass;


    }
    catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e.toString());}
    return myclass;
}

// needed to implement threading.
public void run() {
    TrainNetwork();
    File Net_File = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Number_Recognition_1.ser");
    save(Net_File.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println( "DONE TRAINING :) ^_^ ^_^ :) !\n");
    System.out.println("With Network ERROR = "+Double.toString(get_error())+"\n");
} // run()


// to notify the network to stop training.
public void kill() { die = true; }
```

}

Layer Class:

```
public class LAYER implements Serializable
{
  private   double  Net;
  public    double  Input[];
  // Vector of inputs signals from previous
  // layer to the current layer
  public    NODE    Node[];
  // Vector of nodes in current layer
  // The FeedForward function is called so that
  // the outputs for all the nodes in the current
  // layer are calculated
public void FeedForward() {
    for (int i = 0; i < Node.length; i++) {
        Net = Node[i].Threshold;

        for (int j = 0; j < Node[i].Weight.length; j++)
        {Net = Net + Input[j] * Node[i].Weight[j];
            System.out.println("Net = "+Double.toString(Net)+"\n");
        }

        Node[i].Output = Sigmoid(Net);
        System.out.println("Node["+Integer.toString(i)+".Output = "+Double.toString(Node[i].Output)+"\n");
    }
}

// The Sigmoid function calculates the
// activation/output from the current node
private double Sigmoid (double Net) {
    return 1/(1+Math.exp(-Net));
}

// Return the output from all node in the layer
// in a vector form
public double[] OutputVector() {

    double Vector[];

    Vector = new double[Node.length];

    for (int i=0; i < Node.length; i++)
        Vector[i] = Node[i].Output;

    return (Vector);
}
public LAYER (int NumberOfNodes, int NumberOfInputs) {
    Node = new NODE[NumberOfNodes];

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfNodes; i++)
        Node[i] = new NODE(NumberOfInputs);

    Input = new double[NumberOfInputs];
}

// added by DSK
public NODE[] get_nodes() { return Node; }
}
```

Node Class:

```
 public class NODE implements  Serializable
{
  public    double  Output;
  // Output signal from current node
  public    double  Weight[];
  // Vector of weights from previous nodes to current node
  public    double  Threshold;
  // Node Threshold /Bias
  public    double  WeightDiff[];
  // Weight difference between the nth and the (n-1) iteration
  public    double  ThresholdDiff;
  // Threshold difference between the nth and the (n-1) iteration
  public    double  SignalError;
  // Output signal error
  // InitialiseWeights function assigns a randomly
  // generated number, between -1 and 1, to the
  // Threshold and Weights to the current node
  private void InitialiseWeights() {
    Threshold = -1+2*Math.random();
    // Initialise threshold nodes with a random
    // number between -1 and 1
    ThresholdDiff = 0;
    // Initially, ThresholdDiff is assigned to 0 so
    // that the Momentum term can work during the 1st
    // iteration
    for(int i = 0; i < Weight.length; i++) {
        Weight[i]= -1+2*Math.random();
        // Initialise all weight inputs with a
        // random number between -1 and 1
        WeightDiff[i] = 0;
        // Initially, WeightDiff is assigned to 0
        // so that the Momentum term can work during
        // the 1st iteration
    }
}

public NODE (int NumberOfNodes) {
    Weight = new double[NumberOfNodes];
    // Create an array of Weight with the same
    // size as the vector of inputs to the node

    WeightDiff = new double[NumberOfNodes];
    // Create an array of weightDiff with the same
    // size as the vector of inputs to the node

    InitialiseWeights();
    // Initialise the Weights and Thresholds to the node
}


public double[] get_weights() { return Weight; }
public double get_output() { return Output; }
}
```

I wrote the code in Netbeans exactly like this but it differs in the saving method where the file should be saved!.

How can I load the file correctly so I don't get this exception?

Comment: Unclear if package name was changed in the migration to Android but if so this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358886/how-can-i-deserialize-the-object-if-it-was-moved-to-another-package-or-renamed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this by saving the network to XML file and then load it again  in android so it just took two hours of training instead of days without any Serialization problems , although it took some time to load that XML I serialized it again to neural_network.ser so it will load much faster

I know it's not the best solution but that what I've done.

Here the is the code:

```
  public void SaveToXML(String FileName)throws     
       ParserConfigurationException,     FileNotFoundException,  
        TransformerException, TransformerConfigurationException
     {
  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = parser.newDocument();
    Element root = doc.createElement("neuralNetwork");
    Element layers = doc.createElement("structure");
    layers.setAttribute("numberOfLayers",Integer.toString(this.NumberOfLayers));
    for (int il=0; il<this.NumberOfLayers; il++){
        Element layer = doc.createElement("layer");
        layer.setAttribute("index",Integer.toString(il));
        layer.setAttribute("numberOfNeurons",Integer.toString(this.Layer[il].Node.length));
        if(il==0)
        {
            for(int in=0;in<this.Layer[il].Node.length;in++)
            {
                 Element neuron = doc.createElement("neuron");
                 neuron.setAttribute("index",Integer.toString(in));
                 neuron.setAttribute("NumberOfInputs",Integer.toString(1));
                 neuron.setAttribute("threshold",Double.toString(this.Layer[il].Node[in].Threshold));
                 Element input = doc.createElement("input");
                 double[] weights = this.Layer[il].Node[in].get_weights();
                 input.setAttribute("index",Integer.toString(in));
                input.setAttribute("weight",Double.toString(weights[in]));
                neuron.appendChild(input);
                layer.appendChild(neuron);
            }
            layers.appendChild(layer);

        }
        else
        {
         for (int in=0; in<this.Layer[il].Node.length;in++){
              Element neuron = doc.createElement("neuron");
            neuron.setAttribute("index",Integer.toString(in));
            neuron.setAttribute("NumberOfInputs",Integer.toString(this.Layer[il].Node[in].Weight.length));
            neuron.setAttribute("threshold",Double.toString(this.Layer[il].Node[in].Threshold));
            for (int ii=0; ii<this.Layer[il].Node[in].Weight.length;ii++) {
                 double[] weights = this.Layer[il].Node[in].get_weights();
                Element input = doc.createElement("input");
                input.setAttribute("index",Integer.toString(ii));
                input.setAttribute("weight",Double.toString(weights[ii]));
                 neuron.appendChild(input);                    
            }
            layer.appendChild(neuron);
            layers.appendChild(layer);
         }
    }
    }
    root.appendChild(layers);
    doc.appendChild(root);
    File xmlOutputFile = new File(FileName);
    FileOutputStream fos;
    Transformer transformer;
    fos = new FileOutputStream(xmlOutputFile);
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(fos);
    transformer.setOutputProperty("encoding","iso-8859-2");
    transformer.setOutputProperty("indent","yes");
    transformer.transform(source, result);

    }
```

LoadFromXML Function:

```
   public  BackPropagation LoadFromXML(String FileName)throws 
     ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, ParseException 
    {
    BackPropagation myclass= new BackPropagation();
     DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    File source = new File(FileName);
    Document doc = parser.parse(source);

    Node nodeNeuralNetwork = doc.getDocumentElement();
    if (!nodeNeuralNetwork.getNodeName().equals("neuralNetwork")) throw new ParseException("[Error] NN-Load: Parse error in XML file, neural network couldn't be loaded.",0);
    NodeList nodeNeuralNetworkContent = nodeNeuralNetwork.getChildNodes();
    System.out.print("<neuralNetwork>\n");
    for (int innc=0; innc<nodeNeuralNetworkContent.getLength(); innc++) 
    {
        Node nodeStructure = nodeNeuralNetworkContent.item(innc);
        if (nodeStructure.getNodeName().equals("structure")) 
        { 
            System.out.print("<stucture nuumberOfLayers = ");
            myclass.NumberOfLayers = Integer.parseInt(((Element)nodeStructure).getAttribute("numberOfLayers"));
            myclass.Layer  = new LAYER[myclass.NumberOfLayers];
            System.out.print(Integer.toString(myclass.NumberOfLayers)+">\n");
            NodeList nodeStructureContent = nodeStructure.getChildNodes();
             for (int isc=0; isc<nodeStructureContent.getLength();isc++)
             {
                 Node nodeLayer = nodeStructureContent.item(isc);

                 if (nodeLayer.getNodeName().equals("layer"))
                 {
                     int index = Integer.parseInt(((Element)nodeLayer).getAttribute("index"));
                     System.out.print("<layer index = "+Integer.toString(index)+" numberOfNeurons = ");
                     int number_of_N = Integer.parseInt(((Element)nodeLayer).getAttribute("numberOfNeurons"));
                     System.out.print(Integer.toString(number_of_N)+">\n");
                     if(index==0)
                     {
                         myclass.Layer[0]=new LAYER(number_of_N,800);

                     }
                     else
                     {
                         int j=index-1;
                         myclass.Layer[index]=new LAYER(number_of_N,myclass.Layer[j].Node.length);
                     }
                     NodeList nodeLayerContent = nodeLayer.getChildNodes();
                      for (int ilc=0; ilc<nodeLayerContent.getLength();ilc++)
                      {
                           Node nodeNeuron = nodeLayerContent.item(ilc);
                            if (nodeNeuron.getNodeName().equals("neuron"))
                            {
                                System.out.print("<neuron index = ");
                                int neuron_index = Integer.parseInt(((Element)nodeNeuron).getAttribute("index"));
                                myclass.Layer[index].Node[neuron_index].Threshold = Double.parseDouble(((Element)nodeNeuron).getAttribute("threshold"));
                                System.out.print(Integer.toString(neuron_index)+" threshold = "+Double.toString(myclass.Layer[index].Node[neuron_index].Threshold)+">\n");
                                NodeList nodeNeuronContent = nodeNeuron.getChildNodes();
                                  for (int inc=0; inc < nodeNeuronContent.getLength();inc++)
                                  {
                                      Node nodeNeuralInput = nodeNeuronContent.item(inc);                                    
                                      if (nodeNeuralInput.getNodeName().equals("input"))
                                      {
                                          System.out.print("<input index = ");
                                          int index_input = Integer.parseInt(((Element)nodeNeuralInput).getAttribute("index"));
                                          myclass.Layer[index].Node[neuron_index].Weight[index_input] = Double.parseDouble(((Element)nodeNeuralInput).getAttribute("weight"));
                                          System.out.print(Integer.toString(index_input)+" weight = "+Double.toString(myclass.Layer[index].Node[neuron_index].Weight[index_input])+">\n");
                                      }
                                  }
                            }
                      }


                 }
             }
             System.out.print("</structure");

        }
    }


   return myclass;
 }
```