# ClassNotFoundException with Kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka consumer application, written with Spring Boot 2.0.2.  When I receive the message in my listener, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name. Class not found [com.test.demo.domain.Account]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.demo.domain.Account
```

The class name of the object in the Producer is "**com.test.demo.domain.Account**" but I have a different package and class name in the consumer.

When I re-package the consumer's class name to match the producers, everything works ok.  However, I believe I shouldn't have to do this.

Does anyone know the issue?

**==== UPDATED ====**

**My Producer code:**

```
@Bean public ProducerFactory<String, Account> accountProducerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class.getName());
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps); }

@Bean public KafkaTemplate<String, Account> accountKafkaTemplate() {
    ProducerFactory<String, Account> factory = accountProducerFactory();

    return new KafkaTemplate<>(factory); }
```

**Consumer code:**

```
public ConsumerFactory<String, Account> accountConsumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupName);
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, BytesDeserializer.class.getName());
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configProps);
}

@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<?> kafkaJsonListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Account> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(accountConsumerFactory());
    factory.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());
    return factory;
}
```

**Exception:**

```
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void com.kconsumer.accountconsumer.service.AccountConsumer.accountListener(com.kconsumer.accountconsumer.domain.Account)]
Bean [com.kconsumer.accountconsumer.service.AccountConsumer@444cc791]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to [com.kconsumer.accountconsumer.domain.Account] for GenericMessage [payload={"id":"5b079d0b340d9ef2ac9b6f02","name":"test-400","version":0}, headers={kafka_offset=0, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@6a0a6b0b, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=5b079d0b340d9ef2ac9b6f02, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=ktest, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1527225611820, __TypeId__=[B@2f92e17a}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"id":"5b079d0b340d9ef2ac9b6f02","name":"test-400","version":0}, headers={kafka_offset=0, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@6a0a6b0b, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=5b079d0b340d9ef2ac9b6f02, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=ktest, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1527225611820, __TypeId__=[B@2f92e17a}]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:257)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using `@KafkaListener`, use the `StringDeserializer` or a `ByteArrayDserializer` and add a `StringJsonMessageConverter` `@Bean` to the application context.

Then...

```
@KafkaListener(...)
public void listen(Account account) {
    ...
}
```

...the required type of the account is passed to the converter.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#spring-messaging-message-conversion).

**EDIT**

You don't need a connection factory, boot will detect the converter and wire it in for you.

Here's an example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So50478267Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So50478267Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, Account1> template) {
        return args -> template.send("so50478267", new Account1("foo.inc"));
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "listen", topics = "so50478267")
    public void listen(Account2 account) {
        System.out.println(account);
    }

    @Bean
    public StringJsonMessageConverter jsonConverter() {
        return new StringJsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("so50478267", 1, (short) 1);
    }

    public static class Account1 {

        private final String customer;

        public Account1(String customer) {
            this.customer = customer;
        }

        public String getCustomer() {
            return this.customer;
        }

    }

    public static class Account2 {

        private String customer;

        public Account2() {
            super();
        }

        public String getCustomer() {
            return this.customer;
        }

        public void setCustomer(String customer) {
            this.customer = customer;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Account2 [customer=" + this.customer + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

and

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false

spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

Comment: I tried the change you mentioned but I'm not sure I got it right as it still throws an exception (see updated text in original question).

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I thought the `BytesDeserializer` produces a `byte[]` but it doesn't. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: You saved me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

How did you deserialize your Kafka record object ? If you use deserializers from spring-kafka API such as StringDeserializer, JsonDeserializer.. I think it's not possible to change record object's package name.

If you write custom Serdes for Kafka record yourself then you can do it in deserialization logic by overriding method **readClassDescriptor()** of ObjectInputStream. Please find the sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358886/how-can-i-deserialize-the-object-if-it-was-moved-to-another-package-or-renamed).

Comment: I was trying to avoid custom SerDes if I can help it.  See the updated text in original question for the code.

Comment: What spring-kafka version you are using ? I found a similar issue here  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/610 where Gary Russell said the issue was fixed in the version 2.1.3.

Comment: its' version 2.1.6