# Deserialization exception in kafka

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am getting following error while using kafka-streams.

```
[Kafka Stream] 10:09:26.442 ERROR --- o.a.k.s.e.LogAndFailExceptionHandler: Exception caught     
during Deserialization, taskId: 0_0, topic: t.commodity.promotion, partition: 0, offset: 0
                                    
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class'com.course.kafka.kafkaorder.Broker.Message.PromotionMessage'       
is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, com.course.stream.broker.message, 
com.course.stream.broker.message.*]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize,      
please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable        
trust all (*).          

[Kafka Stream] 10:09:26.444 ERROR --- o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread: stream-thread [kafka-stream-7972        
450a-443b-8b7b-007e9fdf8e4c-StreamThread-1] Encountered the following exception during 
processing and the thread is going to shut down: 
                
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Deserialization exception handler is set to        
fail upon a deserialization error. If you would rather have the streaming pipeline continue after a         
deserialization error, please set the default.deserialization.exception.handler appropriately.
```

My code is

```
@Configuration
public class PromotionJsonSerde {
    
    @Bean
    public KStream<String, PromotionMessage> kStreamPromotionUppercase(StreamsBuilder builder)
    {
        var stringSerde = Serdes.String();
        var jsonSerde = new JsonSerde<>(PromotionMessage.class);

      KStream<String, PromotionMessage> sourceStream = builder.stream("t.commodity.promotion", 
                                Consumed.with(stringSerde, jsonSerde));     
      KStream<String, PromotionMessage> uppercaseStream = sourceStream.mapValues(this::uppercasePromotionCode);

      uppercaseStream.to("t.commodity.promotion-uppercase", Produced.with(stringSerde, jsonSerde));

      return sourceStream;

    }

    private PromotionMessage uppercasePromotionCode(PromotionMessage message)
    {
        return new PromotionMessage(message.getPromotionCode().toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Promotion Code

```
public class PromotionMessage {
    
    private String promotionCode;
     // getters,setters, tostring
}
```

application.yml

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console: "[Kafka Stream] %clr(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:%5p}) %clr(---){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:%wEx}"
  
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: OFF
  kafka:
    listener:
      missing-topics-fatal: false
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

By seeing the error, I tried to add following code in application.yml file. But still I got
same error.

```
spring:
     kafka:    
       producer:
         streams:
          properties:
            default.deserialization.exception.handler: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler,org.springframework.kafka.streams.RecoveringDeserializationExceptionHandler
        consumer:
          properties:
                spring:
                    json:
                      trusted:
                        packages: "*"
      cloud:
        stream:
          kafka:
            streams:
              bindings:
               process-in-0.consumer:
                deserializationExceptionHandler: logAndContinue
```

Why I am getting deserialization error ?
If I check, consumer on terminal , I get the message sent by producer.
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Read the error more carefully. Check out the package names... `The class'com.course.kafka.kafkaorder.Broker.Message.PromotionMessage'       
is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, com.course.stream.broker.message, 
com.course.stream.broker.message.*].` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60286512

Comment: You need to tell the deserializer to ignore the type headers; see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are creating the serde yourself `new JsonSerde<>(PromotionMessage.class);` - we automatically add that class' package to the trusted packages; hence

`trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, com.course.stream.broker.message,  com.course.stream.broker.message.*]`

The property is ignored when you create your own serde. The deserializer is trying to create `com.course.kafka.kafkaorder.Broker.Message.PromotionMessage` which is in a different package; most likely a different class on the producer.

Add this: `((JsonDeserializer) jsonSerde.deserializer()).setUseTypeHeaders(false);` to tell the deserializer to ignore the type information in headers and use the provided fallback type instead.

Comment: I set  spring.kafka.streams.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages= "*"  but still the same error

Comment: Oh; I see you are creating the serde yourself `new JsonSerde<>(PromotionMessage.class);` - we automatically add that class' package to the trusted packages; hence `trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, com.course.stream.broker.message, 
com.course.stream.broker.message.*]` The property is ignored when you create your own serde. The deserializer is trying to create `com.course.kafka.kafkaorder.Broker.Message.PromotionMessage` which is in a different package; most likely a different class on the producer. Add this: `((JsonDeserializer) jsonSerde.deserializer()).setUseTypeHeaders(false);`

Comment: I have added    **spring.kafka.producer.properties.spring.json.add.type.headers: false**  but it did not work.  Did I add what you were saying ?

Comment: NO. As I explained, since you are creating the Serde yourself, you are responsible for configuring it. Configuration via properties only applies if Kafka instantiates the Serde. You need to get a reference to the deserializer from the Serde and set the property programmatically, as I explained in my previous comment.