# Why am I getting java.io.NotSerializableException when the class implements Serializable interface?

Tags: java, serialization

As I try to `serialize` an object with a call , `stashCon.stash()` I get `java.io.NotSerializableException` even when the class `StashCon` implements `Serializable` interface.

What could be the reason for this ?

```
public boolean connect(String username,String password) {
    try {
        Openfire.connection.connect();
        Openfire.connection.login(username,password);
        stashCon = new StashCon(Openfire.connection);
        stashCon.stash(); // CALL THAT ATTEMPTS TO SERIALIZE THE OBJECT
    }catch(Exception exc){
        exc.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

*Following method is of the class `StashCon`*

```
public void stash() {
    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(Constants.BLAB_CONNECTION_FILE));
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(this); // LINE 33
        objectOutputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

*Exception*

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1156)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1474)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1392)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1150)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:326)
at blab.StashCon.stash(StashCon.java:33)
at blab.Openfire.connect(Openfire.java:27)
at blab.ext.gui.SignIn$4.run(SignIn.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: You can't serialize connections, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP If you could elaborate and post it as an answer

Answer (score 7):

Your object contains member variables which are themselves not serializable (an instance of `org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection`).

If you really want to serialize your object, you'll have to do something about that member variable. One option would be to declare that variable as `transient` so that it is not serialized.

On deserialization however, you'll have to handle that member (like reastablishing the connection). For this you could define the method `readObject` which is called during deserialization. In there you can (and probably should) initialize all transient member variables to set your object to a good state.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168348/java-serialization-readobject-vs-readresolve) is also a good question discussing serialization.

Comment: The class only has only one member which is the instance of the class `XMPPConnection` which is not serializable. What do I do to reuse the connection object after the connection has been made once ? Making the user sign-in again at various occasions makes the application slow

Comment: Well, why do you serialize that data to a file in the first place? I assumed you have a good reason for serialization. If you just need to keep the connection up, then store it in some Singleton instance or static member and you have access to it while your program is running. If you want to keep a connection while your program is not running, to reconnect later without prompting for a password, then serialization is not a good solution. To do this you would have to store the username and password which then would compromise the account security of your user.

Answer (score 5):

XMPPConnection is coupled to physical resources (TCP sockets) on the machine in which it resides, therefore it cannot be made serializable.  It is also has an identitiy associated with the connection to the server which cannot be duplicated, since a full JID can only be connected to the same server once, a second connection would force the other one to get disconnected.

The connection should not be put into the session, you have to manage it outside of that scope.

Comment: What do I do when I need to reuse `connection` object from another class ? Reconnecting, will make the application slow on various occasions

Comment: Pass the connection object around within the same JVM. Serialization is neither required nor possible.