# Singleton class with updated parameters in java

Tags: class, singleton

```
public class ThreadSafeSingleton implements Serializable {

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ThreadSafeSingleton [i=" + i + ", str=" + str + "]";
}

int i;
String str;
private static ThreadSafeSingleton instance;

public int getI() {
    return i;
}

public void setI(int i) {
    this.i = i;
}

public String getStr() {
    return str;
}

public void setStr(String str) {
    this.str = str;
}

private ThreadSafeSingleton(){
}

public static synchronized ThreadSafeSingleton getInstance(int i,String str){
    if(instance == null){
        synchronized (ThreadSafeSingleton.class) {
            if(instance == null){
                instance = new ThreadSafeSingleton();
            }
        }
    }
    instance.setI(i);
    instance.setStr(str);
    return instance;
}

public Object readResolve(){
    System.out.println("readResolve executed");

    return getInstance(this.i,this.str);
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
            "B://Serilization//text1.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    ThreadSafeSingleton obj = new ThreadSafeSingleton();
    obj.setI(1);
    obj.setStr("katrina kaif");
    oos.writeObject(obj);
    System.out.println("serilization done");

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("B://Serilization//text1.txt");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    ThreadSafeSingleton copy=(ThreadSafeSingleton) ois.readObject();
    System.out.println("copy "+copy);
    System.out.println("deserilization done");



    }

    }
```

in the above code i have a singleton class containing int i and String str attributes and i have implemented Serializable interface my requirement is that when i serialized a class i will serialize the class with some attributes values on one JVM and when i deserialize on another JVM i should get the same instance of my singleton class but the attributes in the class should get updated with the values i provided during serialization

here on internet i checked the solution i got to use readResolve method there you can write a logic which will set the values of attributes  i provided during serialization of my singleton class so if you will see the code of readResolve i have written a code like this **"return getInstance(this.i,this.str);"** here i have used **"this"** keyword which means a current object is being used therefore i have question
i have doubt that is this code creating new object here as **"this"** refers to the current object apart from the object i created in the getInstance(int i,String str) method can anybody please explain is this breaking singleton ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read up on [Java serialization: readObject() vs. readResolve()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168348/java-serialization-readobject-vs-readresolve). When `readResolve()` is called, your object has already been deserialized from the stream and fully created. Your `this` pointer, in that case, will be the object that the deserialization process has constructed, complete with the `i` and `str` values from the stream. If you use `this.i` and `this.str` to construct the new Singleton, you're not creating a new object with the new JVM's specific parameters.

Comment: It means there will be only one instance of singleton class but using this readResolve() method just updating the values of my old instance.which is my requirement thanks tophyr